# Ocean wave theory

Tags: fluid-dynamics

I am currently reading "HF radio measurements of surface currents" by Stewart and Joy (1974). I have been working through the derivation in the ocean theory section however I am unsure about some steps. The image I have attached is the part I am having difficulty with.

I have understood up to equation [3]. However, I don't understand how they get equations [3a] and [3b]. I have tried simply subbing in: $ f = f_{1} $ and $ c = c_{1} $ into equation 2 to try to get equation [3a] however I don't know how $ \frac{\epsilon U''}{1-\epsilon U} $ would cancel.

Similarly, I have tried to substitute $ f = f_{1} + f_{2} $ and $ c = c_{1} + c_{2} $ into equation 2 to try to find [3b]. The thing that is throwing me off is the mention of "expand the solution of [2] in powers of $ \epsilon $ ". Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not cancel,  but  is $O[\epsilon]$ and so does not affect $f_1$. You do not "derive" 3b from 3a, they are different orders. You     insert  $f=f_1+\epsilon f_2+\epsilon^2f_3+\ldots$ into  3, and then equate to zero the total coefficient of each power of  $\epsilon$. Order $\epsilon^0$ gives 3a, order $\epsilon^1$ gives eq 3b, and so on.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes, doing that leaves me with $ f_{2} '' - k^{2} f_{2} = - \frac{c_{1}U''}{c_{2}+c_{1}(1-\epsilon U)} f_{1} $. Unsure where the $ \epsilon $ on the right hand side of equation 3b comes from.

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to  put the $\epsilon$'s with the $c$'s. Obviously $c_2=0$ at this order, and so is the $\epsilon U$ term. Then the RHS is then  $U'' f_1$.